# Image source not incorrectly recognized by function

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement

I have two images:

```
<img id="img1" src="l1.jpg" usemap="#lb" height="400" border="0" width="300">
<img src="images.jpg" id="img2">
```

Then I have a **JavaScript**:

```
function checkImg () {
    if (document.getElementById('img2').src=="images.jpg") 
    { 
        if (document.getElementById('img1').src=="l1.jpg")
        { 
            window.alert("hi");
        }
    } else { 
        window.alert("bye");
    }
}
checkImg();
```

And a button that activates it:

```
<button type="button" onclick="checkImg()">Click Me!</button>
```

Both images have the source as specified in the script, though it still alerts 'bye' instead of 'hi'.
What's wrong?

Comment: The issue is that the the `src` property returns an absolute URL, not the relative URL you just set.

Comment: @adeneo Whoops... should change that

Comment: @adeneo [second post] How can I use src for a relative URL?

Comment: Please, add and `alert()` with their **src** attributes in your function and tell us what it did :)

Comment: @PDKnight do you mean something like this? 'alert(img2.getAttribute('src') == "images.jpg") ? I'm not really a pro coder... I've just been into coding for a few days...

Comment: like `alert(document.getElementById('img2').src + ', ' + document.getElementById('img1').src)`, but I can see it's solved now :)

Comment: @PDKnight yeah, that works too, I see, thank you. It alerts me the image path, which is intended. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `src` property returns an absolute URL, something like

```
<img src="image.jpg" id="element" />

<script>

    element.src; // http://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg

    element.getAttribute('src'); // image.jpg

</script>
```

In other words, you'd have to use `getAttribute` to get the value of `src` attribute, and not the property, which get you the absolute URL

```
function checkImg() {

    var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
    var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');

    if (img2.getAttribute('src') == "images.jpg") {

        if (img1.getAttribute('src') == "l1.jpg") {

            window.alert("hi");

        } else {

            window.alert("bye");
        }
    }
}

checkImg();
```

Comment: for some reason it does work after copying the code again. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using *getattribute* function, use *hasattribute* function to compare. Then your button will work.

```
<script>
        img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
        img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
        function checkimg() {
        if (img1.hasAttribute("src")=="img/1.jpg") {
            if (img2.hasAttribute("src")=="img/2.jpg"){
                alert("Hello");
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Bye");
        }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I cannot get your code to work :( , and I already have a solution without hasAttribute.